# Where does plink (from Putty package) search for remote commands?

Tags: bash, shell, remote, putty

I need to use `plink` (or something similar if you have something on mind) to get the output from Debian remote machine onto my Windows box. This works e.g. in this case :

`plink 192.168.1.5 "ls" > log.txt`

But when I want to use different command like e.g. `ifconfig` or what is my point of interest my alias for the script I get the error command not found :

```
Server sent command exit status 127
bash: showip: command not found
Disconnected: All channels closed
```

Where does the plink look for commands in this case ? I can easily execute aforementioned commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plink` is running non-interactively and therefore doesn't get your normal shell setup; in particular `$PATH` is going to be the default (typically `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` or some permutation thereof).  In particular it will have neither your personal `bin` directory (wherever you put it) or `/usr/sbin` where many tools like `ifconfig` live.

Comment: You can always use *getconf* to show the details. For example, `ssh localhost '/usr/bin/getconf PATH'` returns **/bin:/usr/bin** on my system.

Comment: Suppose I *want* PATH to include my $HOME/bin when I run a program on a remote linux installation, from Windows, using plink.   (In my case, I am using plink to X-forward an xterm to my Windows machine.)   What is the most accepted way to accomplish that?  Note I prefer a solution that would only affect me, and not other users of the Linux machine.